# argparse custom "optional argument description" when showing -h

Tags: python, argparse

```
parser.add_argument("--something", type=int, nargs=2, help="do something")
```

With the above line what option can i add to make it when i show help, instead of showing this:

```
--something SOMETHING SOMETHING
                    do something
```

it instead does something like this:

```
--something NUMBER LETTER
                    do something
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Add `metavar=('NUMBER','LETTER')`.  (tuple is important here).

Answer (score -1):

Add a [*metavar*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar), `('NUMBER', 'LETTER')`

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--something",
    type=int,
    nargs=2,
    metavar=('NUMBER', 'LETTER'),
    help="do something",
    )
```

From the docs (linked above):

> Different values of `nargs` may cause the `metavar` to be used multiple times. Providing a tuple to `metavar` specifies a different display for each of the arguments

---

*Credit to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) for mentioning this in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648264/argparse-custom-optional-argument-description-when-showing-h/61704557?noredirect=1#comment109048006_61648264)*

Comment: @barny My bad, I forgot to cite hpaulj. Fixed!

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... This does work properly. Any feedback is appreciated.